# Mapping the reverse of a ReferencesAny?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two entity classes (with a common interface, for easy automapping), where one has a generic reference to the other:

```cs
public interface IModelClass
{
  Guid Id { get; set; }
}

class Order : IModelClass
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ISet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

class Attachment : IModelClass
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IModelClass AttachedTo { get; set; }
}
```

I can define the generic reference with `ReferencesAny`:

```cs
mapping.ReferencesAny(x => x.AttachedTo)
       .EntityTypeColumn("entity_type")
       .EntityIdentifierColumn("entity_id")
       .IdentityType<Guid>()
       .MetaType<string>()
       .AddMetaValue<Order>("ORDER")
       .Cascade.None();
```

And this works fine, as long as I only work with attachments directly and don't try to do things from the `Order` side. What I want though, is to map the reverse of the relationship - i.e. what would normally be handled by:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
```

so that I can, say, add attachments to the Order's collection and get them persisted without having to manually go through and set up/save each of the attachments (and I'd have to start passing the session around to get the attachments committed in the same transaction). This doesn't work - it just works normally and creates an `order_id` column on the attachment table.

Is there some way to set up this mapping so that it 'works'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
    .KeyColumn("entity_id")   // to give it the right column to use
    .Where("entity_type = 'ORDER'")  // makes sure that only attachments for the order are loaded
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); // or .Cascade.All(); if Attachments should stay without
```

Comment: But won't this save incorrectly, if you just add an attachment to the order's Attachments set? It'll save without the entity_type entry, which works when using GUIDs but will fall over for other methods. Otherwise, you are reduced to manually assigning the reverse connection, which defeats the point.

Comment: the inverse tells that the other side with the referenceAny is responsible for saving which does in turn put in the right entity_type. You have to assign the order to the `AttachedTo` nonetheless otherwise you have a broken model where the Order has the attachment but the the attachment does not know the order. Just add `void AddAttachment(Attachment a){Attachments.Add(a); a.AttachedTo = this; }` to the order class